# Retrieve a template from Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I'm creating emails from a batch script in symfony 1.4 w/ propel

Trying to set the body of the email to a template

```
player/emailSuccess.php

foreach ($players as $player) {

    if ($users->meetCriteria) {

        //send email from a template
        $email->setBody('player/emailSuccess.php');

    }
}
```

Can I retrieve the email action in the player module and pass it the $player variable, from within a batch script ?

Comment: I think you can. Try loading the `Partial` helper, and make sure you run your script with the application where the player module resides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
 foreach ($players as $player) {

 if ($users->meetCriteria) {

    // use a partial to get the formatted email payload
    $html = $this->getPartial('my_partial', array('MyObject' => $MyObject));
    //send email from a template
    $email->setBody($html);
    .......
    }
 }
```